# :nth-child() pseudoclass isn't working in list

Tags: html, css, stylus

I'm making mobile menu but :nth-child pseudoclass isn't working
here is HTML:

```
<div id="mobilemenu" class="mobilemenu">
            <ul>
                <a href="#"><li class="menuelement">Home</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="menuelement">O Mnie</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="menuelement">Kontakt</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="menuelement">Oferta</li></a>
            </ul>
</div>
```

And here CSS from stylus:

```
.menuelement
        width 100%
        height 20px
        color #fbfbfb
        border 1px solid #DA2825
        padding 15px 0 15px 0
    .menuelement:nth-child(1)
        border-bottom 0
        border-left 0
        border-right 0
    .menuelement:nth-child(2)
        border-left 0
        border-right 0
        border-bottom 0
    .menuelement:nth-child(3)
        border-left 0
        border-right 0
        border-bottom 0
    .menuelement:nth-child(4)
        border-left 0
        border-right 0
        border-bottom 0
```

When i apply changes to first child it is applied to every child instead of first.

Comment: Did one of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 2):

**:nth-child() pseudoclass is working in list**

Your HTML is wrong. 
An `<UL>` need to contain `<li>` and the `<li>` can contain `<a>`

And not sure about your CSS but that should have some of these `{` and some of those `}` and the statements want `:` in the middle and `;` at the end.

```css
.menuelement a {
    color: inherit;
}
.menuelement {
    color: purpleblue;
}
.menuelement:nth-child(1) {
    color: fuchsia;
}
.menuelement:nth-child(2) {
    color: orange;
}
.menuelement:nth-child(3) {
    color: green;
}
.menuelement:nth-child(4) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobilemenu" class="mobilemenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="menuelement"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menuelement"><a href="#">O Mnie</a></li>
            <li class="menuelement"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li class="menuelement"><a href="#">Oferta</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this below css code for menu

```
<style type="text/css">
    .mobilemenu ul li{
        color: purpleblue;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #DA2825;
        padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-left: 0;
        border-right: 0;
    }
    .mobilemenu ul li:nth-child(2) {
        color: orange;
    }
    .mobilemenu ul li:nth-child(3) {
        color: green;
    }
    .mobilemenu ul li:nth-child(4) {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
    <div id="mobilemenu" class="mobilemenu">
            <ul>
                <li class="menuelement"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menuelement"><a href="#">O Mnie</a></li>
                <li class="menuelement"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li class="menuelement"><a href="#">Oferta</a></li>
            </ul>
     </div>
```